# How I can manage having a lookup site column which reference a list inside a sub-site

Tags: 2013, development, lookup-column, site-column, sub-site

I have 5 sub-sites for each of our customers. and inside each sub-site we have a Issue list. now i want to create a new sub-site named "Projects" and this Project sub-site will have entries for all of our customers' projects. so currently i have the following architecture:-

1. /customers/customerA/
2. /customers/customerB/
3. /customers/customerC/
4. /customers/customerD/
5. /customers/customerE/
6. /customers/projects/

now I have created all the site columns and all the content types inside the root site (site collection level).

But now i am trying to achieve the following, but i can not find a straight forward way :-

1. inside the customers subsites' issue lists to add a lookup column which references the Projects list under the Projects sub-site.

but when i created a new lookup column under the root site, i was not able to find the Projects list under the Project sub-site. now i read that to be able to reference a list inside a lookup column, the lookup column and the list need to be inside the same site, while in my case i lookup column is inside the root site, while the Project list is under another subsite. so can anyone adivce what are the approaches i can follow?

i was thinking of this, to create a Mirror Project list under the root site, and using event receivers to be adding/updating/deleting projects entries based on the operations done on the real Project list under the project sub-site. then i can create a lookup column which reference the Mirrir Project lookup list.. now on paper this appraoch should/will work,,, but it will require extra efforts of having extra Mirror list + 3 event receiver which will be firing when users add/update/delete projects items from the real Project list under the Project sub-site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not create the projects list in the root site and create a lookup column that uses this list? That way the issue lists in subsite can use the lookup column showing all projects.

Comment: now i thought of this appraoch also.. but here what i have faced 1) permission for the list need to be managed separately instead of being inherited from the Projects sub-site. 2) when i access the allitems.aspx default iew for the projects list i will get the root site navigation... so if i follow this approach i will solve the lookup column issue.. but i will start facing other issues especially the navigation ...which will show the left side navigation for the root site not the Project sub-site...what do you think ?

Comment: You could use content by query or content by search webpart to display the information from your projects list in the subsite. This way users are not redirect to your root. Other option, if you require the same list view style, would be to export the list view webpart and import it on a page in your subweb. Have a look here: http://blog.cloudbusiness.com/the-company/blog-and-news/displaying-sharepoint-online-2013-lists-to-parent-or-sub-sites